# Dynamically created html tag is not working in IE

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, create-component

I tried to create a HTML Div element dynamically with $A.createComponents();
It's working fine in chrome, safari, firefox, but in IE, it throws an error

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Uncaught
>   error in $A.run() [Expected ':']

Why is it not working in IE ,Is there any workaround to make it work?

**GenerateHtmlTagContainer.app**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <div aura:id="createCmp">

    </div>
</aura:application>
```

**GenerateHtmlTagContainerController.js**

```
({
    doInit : function(cmp, event, helper) {
        var answer = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
        var uiCmps = [];

        var HTMLAttributes = {
            "class": "slds-p-vertical_xx-small"
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
            var tag = {
                "tag": "div",
                "body": answer[i],
                HTMLAttributes
            };

            var uiCmp = [
                "aura:html",
                tag
            ];
            uiCmps.push(uiCmp);
        }

            $A.createComponents(uiCmps,
                function(newCmp, status, errorMessage){
                    if(status === "SUCCESS"){
                        var createCmp = cmp.find("createCmp");
                        createCmp.set("v.body", newCmp);
                    }
            });

    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual issue in the code is, you are not correctly passing the data to the "HTMLAttributes" attribute of the `aura:html` component definition.

> HTMLAttributes    (Map) =>   A map of attributes to set on the html
>   element.

```
 var tag = {
        "tag": "div",
        "body": answer[i],
        HTMLAttributes // you missed the property 'HTMLAttributes' just passed the value only.
 };
```

***Correct code:***

```
 var HTMLAttributes = {
     "class": "slds-p-vertical_xx-small"
 };

 var tag = {
    "tag": "div",
    "body": answer[i],
    "HTMLAttributes" : HTMLAttributes // pass the key 'HTMLAttributes' followed by value.
 };
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue here has nothing to do with Lightning. The code uses a feature of JavaScript called "object literal shorthand property" which is not supported on IE11, but valid on modern browsers: 

            `var tag = {
                "tag": "div",
                "body": answer[i],
                HTMLAttributes
            };`

It's part of a group of object literal extensions also not supported in IE11:
http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-object_literal_extensions

Here are a few articles on the subject:

http://www.benmvp.com/learning-es6-enhanced-object-literals/

https://ariya.io/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand

Lightning doesn't transpile your code, so what you write is what you run.